# The corectness of the following sentences

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, perfect-constructions

Maybe someone consider it too silly but I want to clear it up:

> 1. Are they equal and correct in grammar sense: *You have never really worked / You haven't ever really worked in you life.*
> 2. What would native rather chose: *The director hasn't come / returned / come back yet.*
> 3. Best choice: *What have you been looking at / examining for long?*
> 4. Best choice and how awkward will it be if I replace both parts of the sentence?: *She told me everything when we were coming / going
>      home yesterday.*
> 5. Are they interchangeable?: *How long is it since he wrote to you last / When did he write to you last / How long ago did he write to
>      you last?*
> 6. When we are talking about learning English we use begin, don't we?: *How long is it since you began (not started) learning English?*

In the long run all of them reffer to one exercise and as a result I wrote them in one topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1. You have never really worked / You haven't ever really worked in you life.**

Yes, they are equal in meaning and also are grammatical. Note that you have a typo, it's **your life** instead of **you life**.

> **2. The director hasn't come / returned / come back yet.**

Your three options have slightly different ideas so it depends on what a native speaker want to say to choose one. You would use **come** here when the director has never shown up. You would use **returned** or **come back** (they are equivalent) when the director was there already but he left to go somewhere else but he would come back later.

> **3. What have you been looking at / examining for long?**

Best choice would be **looking at** in a daily life context, it sounds more idiomatic. But in a more specific context, for example when someone is concentrating on their computer at work, then you could say **examining** as well.

> **4. She told me everything when we were coming / going home yesterday.**

Both options work just fine. To me, when you say **coming home** it would be more like that the listener is the person at home, and you're saying to that person that you're coming home to him/her. Otherwise you would say **going home** but honestly there's not much of a difference.

I don't understand your second question here about replacing both parts, replacing them with what? Please specify the question more clearly.

> **5. How long is it since he wrote to you last / When did he write to you last / How long ago did he write to you last?**

They are not entirely interchangeable, though the ideas are pretty much the same. To answer a **how long** question, you would give a duration, e.g. a year. To answer a **when** question, you would, technically speaking, give a point of time, e.g. last year. And to answer a **how long ago** question you would give a duration of time to go back from the moment of speaking, e.g. a year ago (quite similar to **how long**, just need to add **ago**).

Note that for the first question it would be more grammatical to say:

> How long has it been since he wrote to you last?

because you use the word **since**, making the main clause become an action that happened in the past and still at the present.

> **6. How long is it since you began (not started) learning English?**

No, I wouldn't agree so. Both verbs work fine when you talk about learning English. And again, **how long has it been** would be better.

Comment: About replacing: When we wee going home she told me everything.

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Oh you mean switching, not replacing. And nope, sounds just as natural.

Comment: may I ask you one more question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127232/using-present-perfect-continuos-correctly?noredirect=1#comment256614_127232